# Unity .unity-Files (Scenes) open in IDE instead of in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to code the scripts in Unity. Under "Edit" - "Preferences" - "External Tools" - "External Script Editor" I selected VS Code, too.

Opening Scripts works fine, but when I try to open a scene within Unity3D by double clicking on it in the Project View, it opens the code in VS Code.

I tried to remove the External Script Editor from the preferences. Like that, the scenes open in Unity, but when clicking on a script, nothing happens here.

I want, that script-files open in VS Code and my scenes, or all .unity files, open in Unity3D.

Comment: does the scene start in the unity when you double click on it in the windows explorer?

Comment: @Bizhan yes, when I double click with the windows explorer, it starts unity and not VS Code.

Comment: Then it could be a bug and it's better to report it

Comment: @Bizhan where should I properly report this?

Comment: which Unity version are you using? In general: [How To Report Bugs](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Visual Studio Code Editor package to at least 1.1.0 in the Unity Package Manager should fix it - it worked for me!